# Blazor Server - Force user to sign out and re-direct to Login Page

Tags: authorization, blazor

I am using roles based authorization in my Blazor server app.   When a user is viewing any component, something in the database could change behind the scenes.

I would want to force the user to be logged out and back in again if they navigated to any other components. (ie the state of their authentication has changed).

I've tried using the  SignInManager.SignOutAsync() and NavigationManager.Navigate in app.razor to Sign out the user and Navigate to the Login page, but I find that the component they are trying to hit will still draw for a split second before it Navigates away.  Is there a way to have the Navigation manager in the app.razor to immediately navigate away without letting the Page from drawing first.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/175a08dcdccb384a52ba760122cd2eda)
you can inject AuthenticationStateProvider or create custom AuthenticationStateProvider if you need more configuration

Comment: I read this and it makes me nervous to make a custom auth provider.
" For server-side Blazor, it is very unlikely that you should implement a custom AuthenticationStateProvider".     Am I misundertanding something, because once I log into the site the roles are "locked in" until I log out and back in again.  Is this the way it is supposed to work?  If I remove the roles in the aspnetuserroles table, how come the blazor authentication "IsInRole" doesn't detect that change?

Comment: are you using asp net core host for your blazor server side or just connect directly blazor to the database with connection string ?

Comment: I'm using asp.net core host with the built in identity framework that it comes with when you create new VS Blazor app with individual user accounts.

Answer (score 1):

do a client-side POST to a controller method containing SignInManager.SignOutAsync(), followed by NavigationManager.NavigateTo with forceLoad set to true to the Login page